PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser not Returning Anything
I'm trying to use the PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser for the first time from here - https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/docs/1.9/index.html
Unfortunately, I'm having an issue where it's not returning anything no matter what I try.
Any help would be much appreciated. My code is below:
<?php
    require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/assets/html_dom_parser/simple_html_dom.php');
    $amazonASIN = "B0C89F1V5S";
    $html = file_get_html("http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/".$amazonASIN);
    if($html) {
        $price = $html->find('.a-price-whole', 0);
        print_r($price);
        echo 'price is '.$price;
    }
?>

I'm essentially trying to get the price from - https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B0C89F1V5S
Thanks!

There's no class="a-whole-price" in the HTML there. It's added dynamically by JavaScript.

Did you try using View Source on the web page to see what the HTML is?

Simple HTML DOM also has a size limit, it returns null if the document is too big.

@Barmar Thanks for your quick reply. How can I retrieve the price if the parser is unable to select the element as it's added by JavaScript by Amazon?

@LewisHardisty: In that case you're looking for more of a "headless browser".  Selenium is a popular tool for this.  (I'm not familiar with its usage in PHP.  And there may be other similar products as well.)  Essentially what tools like that do is act as an entire web browser "in-memory".  file_get_html just makes one HTTP request and gets that one initial response.  Whereas tools with full browser engines will also fetch other page resources as needed, execute JavaScript code, update the DOM, etc. This allows you to observe and parse the resulting HTML from that logic, just like a browser.
